# Add a filter to coloredlogs

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to use coloredlogs to add colour to the console.
So the code creates a StreamHandler for the console, and adds a filter.
This in itself works. BUT the coloredlogs adds another duplicate output that does not get filtered.
It seems to run through 'sys.err' without being caught by the filter.

How do I add a filter to the coloredlog?

```
import logging
from func import std_func
import sys
import coloredlogs


class BlockFilter(logging.Filter):

    def filter(self, record):
        allow = True

        if record.msg.startswith('Hello'):
            allow = False

        return allow


def std_func(val):
    log = logging.getLogger('')
    log.warning('Hello world.')

    return val * 2.0


def config_logging():

    block_filter = BlockFilter()

    sh = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    sh.addFilter(block_filter)
    sh.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    logger = logging.getLogger('')  # root logger
    logger.addHandler(sh)


def main():

    config_logging()
    coloredlogs.install(logger=logging.getLogger(''))

    result = std_func(3.12)
    print(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

The output from the coloredlog log always contains the 'Hello world' that I'm trying to filter out.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `coloredlogs.install()` removes the previous handler and replaces it with a custom one. If you want to have a Filter you need to add it to this handler after the call to install. The following code shows a working example:

```
import coloredlogs
import logging

class BlockFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return not record.msg.startswith('Hello')

coloredlogs.install()

for handler in logging.getLogger().handlers:
    handler.addFilter(BlockFilter())

logging.warning('Hello this is blocked')
logging.warning('this is shown')
```

As an aside: `logging.getLogger()` and `logging.getLogger('')` are the same, and `coloredlogs.install()` defaults the logger argument to the root logger anyway.